# Updating MySQL with PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{ 
$productID = $_POST['pid'];
$cat_id = $_POST['cat_id']; 
$name = $_POST['name'];  
$picture = $_POST['picture'];  
$description = $_POST['description'];  
$me_level = $_POST['me_level'];  
$pe_level = $_POST['pe_level']; 
$runs = $_POST['runs'];
$copy = $_POST['copy'];  
$stock_level = $_POST['stock_level'];  
$price = $_POST['price'];

//INSERT   
$query2 = "UPDATE products SET cat_id =' $cat_id', name =' $name', picture =' $picture', description =' $description', me_level =' $me_level',  pe_level =' $pe_level', run =' $runs', copy =' $copy', stock_level =' $stock_level', price =' $price' WHERE serial=$productID"; 
$result = mysql_query($query2); 

if( $result ){
echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
<strong>Success!</strong> Product has been updated.
</div>';
}
else{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-error'>
<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</button>
<strong>Error!</strong> failed again ".$productID."
</div>";
}
};
```

I have inserted a sheet – that works fine – but I can't get this working.

Comment: What's up with all the leading spaces in your column data? What error are you getting from your DB (please search on how to get that)?

Comment: If you are using mysql_* functions and not mysqli or pdo don´t insert $_Posts just like this...use "$yourpost = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[yourPost]);"

Comment: Instead of saying that something "is not working" you should be more precise and describe 1) what you're trying to do 2) what specifically fails and 3) what you've tried to solve it.

Comment: you have extra space in `cat_id =' $cat_id', name =' $name',` etc ...

Comment: FOR WHO ARE ANSWERING : `$productID` is integer, then no need to quotes !

Comment: `mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());` Add this and check the mysql error

Comment: Why cant you  yourself see the error by using MySQL error handling functions? Wont it let you know better what's the error in the query?

Comment: You should add **why** it isn't working

Comment: its not updating database i would have thought that pretty obvious really

Comment: @Krish R thx very much found error and fixed you sir are a superstar

Comment: i am a total learner at coding , i find i learn better just getting on with it rather than slow baby steps ,,,, i will be sure to use this in future `mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());` thank you

Comment: `mysql_*` are deprecated. for the future, use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

Here `WHERE serial=$productID`. It should be `WHERE serial='$productID'`

Comment: @ Alireza Fallah:- It is safe practice to put single quotes around the variable whether it is integer or not.

Comment: @RolenKoh: That wouldn't matter if you've validated the variable as an int (for example, if it's coming from an int/bigint/etc. column, or if it's user input - sanitize it)

Comment: @RolenKoh :  yes it is, but you cant say this is the error of code. its just a friendly advise

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
$query2 = "UPDATE products SET cat_id ='". $cat_id ."', name ='". $name ."', picture ='". $picture ."', description ='". $description. "', me_level ='". $me_level ."',  pe_level ='". $pe_level ."', run ='". $runs ."', copy ='". $copy ."', stock_level ='". $stock_level ."', price ='". $price ."' WHERE serial= '". $productID. "'";
```

Comment: What difference does it make?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
$query2 = "UPDATE products SET cat_id ='$cat_id', name ='$name', 
picture ='$picture', description ='$description',
me_level ='$me_level',  pe_level ='$pe_level', run ='$runs', 
copy ='$copy', stock_level ='$stock_level', price ='$price' 
WHERE `serial`=$productID";
```

The field name `serial` is quoted with (`). It is needed because "serial" is a keyword in MySQL.